# WooCommerce order complete email custom meta fields

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, metadata

We have recently updated a client's WordPress WooCommerce installation to 3.1.x. Subsequently, we had to update some of our custom code, since the method used was now deprecated and was throwing warnings.

The code added meta data for a shipment tracking code and custom coupon to the email sent to the customer on order complete.
This was the code before the update:

`<h2 style="color:#464446">Tracking Code: <?php echo get_post_meta( $order->id, 'parzel_tracking_code', true ); ?></h2>
<?$custom_coupon = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'custom_coupon_message', true );`

and after the update:

`<h2 style="color:#464446">Tracking Code: <?php echo $order->get_meta( 'parzel_tracking_code', true ); ?></h2>
<?$custom_coupon = $order->get_meta( 'custom_coupon_message', true );`

However, this is now causing a new issue: automatic emails sent to customers do not display the meta data anymore. If the same on-order-completed mail is manually resent within WooCommerce(even immediately after the order is made), all the data in the newly sent email appears normally, like it did before the update.

Any thoughts on how to get the emails back into working order?

Update:

We're using this code in the "customer-completed-order.php", as an overridden template file in our custom wordpress theme. Our code is inserted right after

```
`do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, 
$plain_text, $email );`
```

the file is version 2.5.0 and nothing else is changed other than the mentioned addition

Here's the link to the file: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.1/templates/emails/customer-completed-order.php

Comment: maybe is it related to the mail templating system after the update? If i remember well, updates can mess it quite regularly. Maybe a default template is being used on automatic sending?

Comment: What are you using to include this new updated code for email notifications, a hooked function or the woocommerce templates themselves… Please update your question with more details around this, as we can not reproduce or test your issue…